# When the summands of a positive definite matrix are positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms

Let $A,B$ be two real symmetric matrices. Let $C = A+B$ be a positive-definite matrix. Write $C>0$ for $C$ being positive-definite. Suppose that $A>0 \implies C>0$ and $B > 0 \implies C>0$, can anything non-trivial be said about when $$C > 0 \implies A>0? \hspace{1cm} \text{or} \hspace{1cm} C>0 \implies B>0?$$

Comment: $2A+(-A)=A, (-A)+2A=A, A+(-A)=0$.